# Test Class for Trigger not providing full coverage

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I am having problems creating a test class to cover a small amount of code, but my test is not proving full coverage.

## Trigger

```
trigger deletedOppLineItem_Tr on OpportunityLineItem (before delete) {

    for(OpportunityLineItem e: trigger.old)
    {
        String OpportunityLineItemID= e.Id;
        String OpportunityId=e.OpportunityId;
        Datetime d= System.now();
        System.debug(e);
        deletedOppLineItem__c myCustomObject = new deletedOppLineItem__c (datenTime__c = d, oppId__c = OpportunityId, oppLineItemID__c=OpportunityLineItemID,name ='Abcd');
        insert myCustomObject;
        System.debug(myCustomObject);
    }

}
```

## Test Class

```
@istest
public class TestDeletedOppLineItem {

    static testMethod void testoppinsert(){

        date datetimes = date.today();

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert acc;

        Campaign cmp1 = new Campaign(name= 'testcampaign');

        //get standard pricebook
        Pricebook2  standardPb = [select id, name, isActive from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];

        Pricebook2 pbk1 = new Pricebook2 (Name='Test Pricebook Entry 1',Description='Test Pricebook Entry 1', isActive=true);
        insert pbk1;

        Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (Name='Test Product Entry 1',Description='Test Product Entry 1',productCode = 'ABC', isActive = true);
        insert prd1;

        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry (Product2ID=prd1.id,Pricebook2ID=standardPb.id,UnitPrice=50, isActive=true);
        insert pbe1;

        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity (Name='Opp1',StageName='Stage 0 - Lead Handed Off',CloseDate=Date.today(),Pricebook2Id = pbe1.Pricebook2Id, AccountId = acc.id, campaignid = cmp1.id);
        insert opp1;

        OpportunityLineItem lineItem1 = new OpportunityLineItem (OpportunityID=opp1.id,PriceBookEntryID=pbe1.id, quantity=4, totalprice=200);
        insert lineItem1;

        delete lineItem1;

        deletedOppLineItem__c myCustomObject = new deletedOppLineItem__c (datenTime__c = datetimes, oppId__c = opp1.Id, oppLineItemID__c=lineitem1.id,name ='Abcd');
        insert myCustomObject;

    }

}
```

Comment: what did not covered here. Also check if your trigger is Active.

Comment: You've got DML in a for loop, and no asserts in your test method.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: The trigger was written for us, we have an urgent requirement to deploy and i cannot achive any test coverage

Comment: i tried adding this but still no coverage

test.startTest(); 
    
OpportunityLineItem lineItem1 = new OpportunityLineItem (OpportunityID=opp1.id,PriceBookEntryID=pbe1.id, quantity=4, totalprice=200);
insert lineItem1;       

delete lineItem1;
    
deletedOppLineItem__c myCustomObject = new deletedOppLineItem__c (datenTime__c = datetimes, oppId__c = opp1.Id, oppLineItemID__c=lineitem1.id,name ='Abcd');

    try{
    insert myCustomObject;
    system.assertEquals(myCustomObject.oppId__c,opp1.id);
        
    }
    catch (DMLException e){
        
    }
   
test.stopTest();

Comment: What type of field is oppLineItemID__c on the deletedOppLineItem__c  object?

Comment: text feild (50)

Comment: Your test does not actually test anything it just flips the switch but does not ensure anything happened

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you should NEVER (like really) call DML operations in a for loop. This can hit the [governors limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) on your org provoke errors.

Update your trigger code to this:

```
trigger deletedOppLineItem_Tr on OpportunityLineItem (before delete) {

    // Instanciate a list of records to insert after the for loop
    List<deletedOppLineItem__c> myCustomObjectList = new List<deletedOppLineItem__c>();
    // Populate this list with the deleted records informations
    for(OpportunityLineItem e: trigger.old) {
        System.debug(e);
        myCustomObjectList.add(new deletedOppLineItem__c(datenTime__c = System.now(), oppId__c = e.OpportunityId, oppLineItemID__c = e.Id,name = 'Abcd'));
    }
    system.debug('My custom object list: ' + myCustomObjectList);
    // Check the list size before doing any DML operation
    if(myCustomObjectList.size() > 0) {
        insert myCustomObjectList;
    }
}
```

Basically, it does the exact same thing, but it is a way better practice this way since you won't hit the DML operations limit.

Then update your test class to the following:

```
@istest
public class TestDeletedOppLineItem {

    static testMethod void testoppinsert(){

        date datetimes = date.today();

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert acc;

        Campaign cmp1 = new Campaign(name= 'testcampaign');

        //get standard pricebook
        Pricebook2  standardPb = [select id, name, isActive from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];

        Pricebook2 pbk1 = new Pricebook2 (Name='Test Pricebook Entry 1',Description='Test Pricebook Entry 1', isActive=true);
        insert pbk1;

        Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (Name='Test Product Entry 1',Description='Test Product Entry 1',productCode = 'ABC', isActive = true);
        insert prd1;

        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry (Product2ID=prd1.id,Pricebook2ID=standardPb.id,UnitPrice=50, isActive=true);
        insert pbe1;

        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity (Name='Opp1',StageName='Stage 0 - Lead Handed Off',CloseDate=Date.today(),Pricebook2Id = pbe1.Pricebook2Id, AccountId = acc.id, campaignid = cmp1.id);
        insert opp1;

        OpportunityLineItem lineItem1 = new OpportunityLineItem (OpportunityID=opp1.id,PriceBookEntryID=pbe1.id, quantity=4, totalprice=200);
        insert lineItem1;

        delete lineItem1;

        // Select the record supposed to be created on trigger delete, always target a list when doing so to avoid null pointer exceptions.
        List<deletedOppLineItem__c> deletedItemList = [Select oppId__c, oppLineItemID__c
                                                       From deletedOppLineItem__c
                                                       Where oppLineItemID__c= :lineItem1.Id];

        // Check that the list is not empty, since a record should have been created for the deleted one
        System.assert(deletedItemList.size() > 0);

        // And check that this record (first element of the list) is matching the deleted one (checking the opp id here)
        System.assertEquals(opp1.Id, deletedItemList[0].oppId__c);
    }
}
```

Remember that code coverage for code coverage is not an appropriate option, you should always aim for the 100% code coverage passing and non-passing unit tests.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: You should never have a primary goal of 100% coverage. Your goal should be to test business processes and outcomes along with edge cases and negative cases. Coverage will come organically. Then and only then review coverage and test those uncovers places or determine if the code is even necessary

Comment: You're right Eric, that's what I meant actually.